# java - input dialog validation

Tags: java, swing, validation, input, a-star

I'm trying to implement **A* algorithm** in java. The user is requested to type the width and height of the grid-to-be. My problem is in validating that input. Here is my code:

```
public class Map extends java.awt.Panel implements Serializable
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
String rows =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                "Συμπληρώστε τον αριθμό γραμμών του πλέγματος: \n",
                "Δημιουργία πλέγματος",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
String cols =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                "Συμπληρώστε τον αριθμό στηλών του πλέγματος: \n",
                "Δημιουργία πλέγματος",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

int rowsnum = Integer.parseInt(rows); 
int colsnum = Integer.parseInt(cols);
GridCell gridCell[][] = new GridCell[rowsnum][colsnum];

public Map()
{
        super();

    setLayout(new GridLayout(rowsnum,colsnum)); 
    for(int i=0;i<rowsnum;i++){ 
        for(int j=0;j<colsnum;j++){
           gridCell[i][j] = new GridCell();
           gridCell[i][j].setPosition(new Point(i,j));
           add(gridCell[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to check the input in a new method, but my problem is that I need to have access to `rowsnum` , `colsnum` and `gridcell[]` from the other classes of my program.

I'm new in Java and I'd very much appreciate any help. :-)

Comment: `My problem is in validating that input.`, please validating that input == or != mouse or key events on/into GridCell

Comment: Could you please explain that a bit more?

Comment: please whats action is == validating input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution i could think was

Validating width/height numbers with If

```
public class Map extends java.awt.Panel implements Serializable
    {      
    String width =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give Width (>5 , <30)");
    int w = Integer.parseInt(width);

    String height =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give height (>5 , <30)");
    int h = Integer.parseInt(height);

    GridCell gridCell[][] = new GridCell[w][h];

    public Map()
    {
    super();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(w,h)); 

    if ( w < 5)
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "Number out of Limits ,application closing" );
     System.exit(0);}
    if ( w > 30)
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "Number out of Limits ,application closing" );
     System.exit(0);}
    if ( h < 5)
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "Number out of Limits ,application closing" );
     System.exit(0);}
    if ( h > 30)
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "Number out of Limits ,application closing" );
     System.exit(0);}


        for(int i=0;i<w;i++){ 

            for(int j=0;j<h;j++){
               gridCell[i][j] = new GridCell();
               gridCell[i][j].setPosition(new Point(i,j));
               add(gridCell[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Validating string input error with try-catch on public main

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

try{    
AStar2 test = new AStar2();                   
test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
test.setDefaultCloseOperation(test.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);}
catch(NumberFormatException e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "BLOODY HELL DONT PUT STRINGS FOR INPUT, APPLICATION IS CLOSING , TRY BETTER NEXT TIME" );}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now your rowsnum, colsnum, and GridCells are variables within your "Map" class.

In order to access this as instance variables from other classes,

```
public int rowsnum = // something
public int colsnum = // something
public GridCell girdCell[][] = //something
```

"public" means the variable can be accessed from outside the class.

and outside your Map class,

```
Map m = new Map();
int rowsnum = m.rowsnum
int colsnum = m.colsnum
// access instance variables
```

However, it is better to create getters and setters for your instance variables.

That is, to create separate methods for getting and setting these variables.

```
public int getRowsNum() {
    return rowsnum;
}
```

and such.

Comment: I've put the validation in a method, however when I declare rows, cols, gridcell public, I have an error "Illegal start of expression".

Comment: `public void validate() {
        if (rows==null ||rows.isEmpty()||!rows.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "Δεν πληκτρολογήσατε έγκυρο αριθμό!",
        "Λάθος είσοδος",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
    } ` However I'm not sure how to call it!   I added an `else {public int rowsnum = Integer.parseInt(rows); 
   public int colsnum = Integer.parseInt(cols);
   public GridCell gridCell[][] = new GridCell[rowsnum][colsnum];}` and that's where the error shows.

Comment: those string variables rows & cols should be declared outside the Map class. Put it in the main() function, and after you get the values for rows and cols, pass it into the Map constructor and set rowsnum and colsnum.

Answer (score 1):

you can access them through an Map class object (change access modifier to public of those variables )

Example : in class B

```
public class Test {
    public static void  main(String args[]){
        Map someMap = new Map();

        //Access gridCell 
        someMap.gridCell;

        //Access rowsnum
        someMap.rowsnum;

        //Access colsnum
        someMap.colsnum;
    }
}
```

Or you can made those as static and access them with class name

Example :
    Map.rowsnum;

Comment: Yes, I have no problem accessing them the way the code is right now, but if I initialize them inside a method of Map, then how do I access them from other methods of class Map or from other classes?